# Close b-modal BootrstrapVue from the outside

Tags: vue.js

How can I hide a [b-modal](https://bootstrap-vue.github.io/docs/components/modal/) component from the outside?

Answer (score 5):

In your `<template>`:

```
<b-button v-b-modal="'myModalId'">
    Open Modal
</b-button>

<b-modal :id="myModalId">
    <div>
        Ami du soir, bonsoir !
    </div>
    <b-btn @click="hideModal(id)">Close Me</b-btn>
</b-modal>
```

In your `<script>` **export default { }** paragraph:

```
methods: {
    hideModal (id) {
        this.$root.$emit('bv::hide::modal',id)
    }
}
```

More details [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#emitting-events-on-root).

Answer (score 4):

All `b-modal` components watch the `hide::modal` event and check if the `id` corresponds to them, in which case they hide. So, simply emit this event using

```
this.$root.$emit('hide::modal', 'your modal id')
```